# How do we use setMinimumLetancy using FirebaseJobDispatcher?

Tags: android, job-scheduling, firebase-job-dispatcher, jobintentservice

I am using **FirebaseJobDispatcher** for posting the data.

```
 FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(DetectedActivitiesIntentService.this));

    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(SendCarProbeDataService.class) // the JobService that will be called
            .setTag(tripId)
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK) 
            .setExtras(bundle) 
            .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

I have noticed that my posting service runs after some duration.
When I research on it, I get to know that there is a JobInfo which have the property to set **setMinimumLetancy(0)** to run the service as quick as possible.

```
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(tripId, SendCarProbeDataService.class)
                .setMinimumLatency(0)
                .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                .setExtras(bundle).build();
```

But I need to know the difference between **Job** and **JobInfo** and how I use setMinimumLetancy in **Job**?

Answer (score 0):

with job info you can specify the constraints of the job. if you want to execute your job at specific time then use

```
.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(x, y))
```

x is the window starting time
y is the window ending time

eg:.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(10, 20))

the job will execute between the time 10 to 20 seconds...

for immediate execution use

```
.setTrigger(Trigger.NOW)
```